# Merging lists of dictionaries

Tags: c#

Suppose we have lists of dictionaries ld1 and ld2. Both have some dictionary objects in common. Suppose dictionary object "a" is in both lists. I want to merge the list of dictionaries such that is same object is in both lists it should come only once in merged list.

Comment: The same dictionary will not be repeated with Union, not the given object stored in your dictionaries.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata 5/9 accepted is [not that bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88046/is-58-accept-rate-bad).

Answer (score 2):

[LINQ's `.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731) should work nicely:

```
oneList.Union(twoList)
```

If you need a `List`, just call `ToList()` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge lists, [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx)

```
ld1.Union(ld2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with custom object or class, simple enumerable.Union will not work.

You have to create your custom comparer.

To do this create a new class that implements the IequalityComparer then use this as follows

oneList.Union(twoList, customComparer)

Some code sample is shown below:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

// Custom comparer for the Product class
class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return x.Code == y.Code && x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashProductName = product.Name == null ? 0 : product.Name.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the Code field.
        int hashProductCode = product.Code.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
    }

}
```

Detailed explanation is shown in the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dic1.Add(1, "One");
dic1.Add(2, "Two");
dic1.Add(3, "Three");
dic1.Add(4, "Four");
dic1.Add(5, "Five");

Dictionary<int, string> dic2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dic2.Add(5, "Five");
dic2.Add(6, "Six");
dic2.Add(7, "Seven");
dic2.Add(8, "Eight");

Dictionary<int, string> dic3 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dic3 = dic1.Union(dic2).ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
```

The result is dic3 having eight values with the duplicate key-value (5, "Five") removed.